# can I send Firebase Cloud Messaging to 50K - 100K users simultaneously?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I probably need to send a push notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging to around 50K - 100K users using cloud function

here is the code on my cloud function to send FCM

```
const sendFCMPromises = []

devicesQuerySnapshot.docs.forEach( deviceSnapshot => {

       // get user device FCM token
       const userFCMToken = deviceSnapshot.data().fcmToken

       const payload = {
          data: {
              body: body,
              title: title,
              type: type,
              imagePath: imagePath
          }
       }

       const p = admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userFCMToken,payload)
       sendFCMPromises.push(p)
            
})

return await Promise.all(sendFCMPromises)
```

I have tried to read the FCM [Throttling and Scaling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#throttling-and-scaling) and also [cloud function limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas)

I just focus to these two limits

1. Max function duration 540 s from cloud function
2. maximum rate of 240 messages/minute and 5,000 messages/hour to a single device, from FCM.

I believe I will not hit those limits.  but I am new in Firebase, I am worried that I will hit some limits that I am not considered yet.

is there any other limits that will make this operation fail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes, you can do it. The amount of messages that you can send will be limited only by the already cited limits.

There are another limitations but are specified on the documentation that you linked, and don't impact directly your use case, except [maybe](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#topics_throttling):

> The topic subscription add/remove rate is limited to 3,000 QPS per project.

If you're using topics.

As a general recommendation, start to see how your application is behaving and make the necessary adjustments, although planning is important, it's also important to be [agile](https://www.a-connect.com/knowledge/agile-the-art-of-adapting-to-change-and-innovation/#:%7E:text=Agile%20is%20a%20collective%20concept,enable%20direct%20feedback%20from%20them.), so for example if you're almost reaching a quota or hard limit change the way you deliver your messages to diminish the effects.